# How to resolve "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::adoptDocument()'"

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, relocation

I am trying to build a C++ program in Eclipse that uses a library xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4 (binary). I see the below errors ...

---

1. `relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::adoptDocument()`
2. `undefined reference to xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::adoptDocument()`

---

Gone through a link on stackoverflow ([What does this GCC error "... relocation truncated to fit..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486116/what-does-this-gcc-error-relocation-truncated-to-fit-mean)) and understood what type of error is this but did not get a solution on how to resolve it.

Environment I am using: Cygwin64 on Windows8.1 and Eclipse configured to use Cygwin C++ compiler. Tried both xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4 as well as xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4 and got the same error.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem by using the `libxerces-c` and `libxerces-c-devel` from Cygwin setup (re-ran the setup with these two additional packages). I Got rid of above errors as well as `signal 11 [Segmentation fault]` error. These binaries are found to be suitable for Cygwin environment.